# Choosing specific sql data within curly braces

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, joomla3.3

I apologize in advance for my limited understanding of the terminology used.

What I'm trying to do is call data from a specific row and column, I've narrowed down my query that far - the issue I'm having is choosing the proper data inside is inside curly braces separated by commas.  I've uploaded a screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCSGV.jpg

This is my php query ($catId is a value for the current category which is working correctly.)

```
<?php $db = JFactory::getDBO(); ?>
<?php $db->setQuery("SELECT params FROM #__categories WHERE id = '".$catId."'"); ?>
<?php $catimg = $db->loadResult(''); ?>
<?php echo $catimg; ?>
```

The echo is just to see if its pulling the right data and this is what its showing:

{"category_layout":"","image":"images/banners/white.png","color":"#000000"}

The data I'm trying to get is from "image", then echo it into an image tag -but this is where I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Depending on where you are calling this from you could also use the api. If you already have a category object there is no reason to do another query, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you would like something like:

```
<?php
$db->setQuery("SELECT params FROM #__categories WHERE id = '".$catId."'");
$catinfo = json_decode($db->loadResult(''), true);
$catimg = $catinfo['image'];
echo $catimg;
?>
```

The info in the curly braces is in the JSON format which could be simply parsed with php built-in function `json_decode(jsonString)`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was using Joomla 3.3.  I'm not sure if that affects your answer (which is appreciated by the way), but it tossed me this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /html/mod_rseventspro_upcoming/default.php on line 43

**line43=<?php echo $catimg['image']; ?>**

Comment: @TylerAncell, use `json_decode(..., true)` to have the object decoded as an array. Then you can extract the `image` component. Otherwise you can use `$catinfo->image` to access `$catinfo` as an object.

Comment: A fancier (and, in this context, way crazier) possibility would be to teach MySQL to read JSON :-) -- http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/04/08/json-parsing-in-mysql-using-common-schema/

Comment: It would be nice but there would have to be installed `common_schema` or he would have the rights to install it.